# Встраиваемые типы

Tags: golang

```
type PrivateKey struct {
    rsa.PrivateKey
}

func GenerateKey() (*PrivateKey) {
    privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error)
    }
    return privateKey
}
```

Соответственно возникает ошибка

> cannot use privateKey (type *rsa.PrivateKey) as type *PrivateKey in return argument

Можно ли это исправить, что бы GenerateKey возвращала тип PrivateKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроенный тип как бы внутри вашего типа. Так что:

```
var err error
privateKey.PrivateKey, err = rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
```